# Unix Concat multiple lines between specific keywords into a single line

Tags: unix, string-concatenation

My team gets Teradata DDL files generated through a front end tool. These files need to be corrected before executing.
A step in this is getting the DDL command on a single line

E.g.
create table ABC  
(column A varchar2(100),
column B number(10)
);

replace view ABC_v as 
select columnA, column B from 
ABC;

should change to

create table ABC (column A varchar2(100),column B number(10));

replace view ABC_v as select columnA, column B from ABC;

In short, I am looking to replace every new line character with single space in a multi-line string. 
The string can start with either **create, replace** or **drop** and it will always end with a **;** (semicolon)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think you need to update your example. Otherwise, all we can say is that something like `sed -e 's/\. \./../g` would erase all the spaces between the groupings of dots...

Comment: I still don't see a difference, other than an occasional space being inserted or removed. It's not at all clear what you are looking for, or what you have actually accomplished...

Comment: Updated again, hope it is clear now

Comment: Will there ever be other commands than the create/replace/drop in the code? Will the commands ever be a single line on input or are they always multiple lines?  Is there always a blank line between commands?  Is there a prize for the most different commands that can do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution in shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read first rest; do
  case "$first" in
    create|replace|drop) echo "" ;;
  esac
  printf "%s %s " "$first" "$rest"
done < inputfile
echo ""
```

This adds a blank line to the beginning of the output because I'm lazy.  But you see the logic, I'm sure.  To avoid the blank line, you can use a temporary variable to determine whether you've actually started pulling in input data yet.

You could do something sort-of similar using awk:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    a["create"];
    a["replace"];
    a["drop"];
  }

  $1 in a && h {
    print substr(h,2);h="";
  }

  {
    h=h" "$0;
  }

  END {
    print substr(h,2);
  }
' inputfile
```

Instead of simply prepending a newline before keywords, this solution builds lines of output in variables, then prints them when they're complete.

Alternately, you could use sed to implement the same idea:

```
sed -rne '/^(create|replace|drop) /{;x;s/\n/ /g;/./p;d;};H;${;x;s/\n/ /g;p;}' inputfile
```

In all three of these solutions, I haven't bothered to check whether the input string ends in a semicolon.  You can add that check to each of them once you decide how you want to *handle* that failure.  (Report an error?  Send the command via email?  Ignore it?)

Note also that DDL, like SQL, should be able to interpret commands provided on multiple lines.  SQL is whitespace agnostic -- an unquoted newline should be the same as a space (though perhaps Teradata behaves differently).

Comment: I expect it is the editing/correcting process, not the Teradata SQL, that requires the statements one per line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - ah, then perhaps this isn't so useless an answer. :)